# putIfAbsent can have more then one key?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this putIfAbsent, can I have 3 keys in a putIfAbsent? For example _items.putIfAbsent((product.named, color, size)

```
_items.putIfAbsent((product.named),() => CartItem(
          name: product.named,
          price: product.priced,
          quantity: count,
          image: product.imaged,
          cor: cor,
          tamanho: tamanho,
        ),
      );
```

I wanted 3 keys to be able to make a selection, if the product doesn't have the same name, size and color. Added a new product to the list (for example, with a different color than the existing product)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `Set<CartItem>` instead of a list with `CartItem` overriding the `==` method like this:

```
@override
bool operator ==(Object other) {
  if (other is! CartItem) return false;
  return this.color == other.color 
    && this.name == other.name
    && this.size == other.size;
}
```

Of course we need to override the `hashCode` method aswell (thanks to [Randal Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22483/randal-schwartz) for the remark):

```
@override
int get hashCode => Object.hash(this.name, this.color, this.size);
}
```

Comment: don't forget to override hashCode if you override == as described in https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/hash_and_equals.html.